# Link in paper-item inside paper-menu-button

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to build a little Flask project using Polymer. I don't think the flask aspect is messing with me. When I click on the 'Edit Species' paper-item I don't go anywhere.

```
<body>
    <core-header-panel flex>
        <core-toolbar class="medium-tall">
            <paper-menu-button icon="menu">
                <paper-item label="Home" center horizontal layout flex></paper-item>
                <paper-item label="Edit Species" center horizontal layout flex>
                    <a href="/speciesEdit"></a>
                </paper-item>
                    ...more...
            </paper-menu-button>
            ...and so on...
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the link to work inside a paper-menu-button?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have working code:

```
 <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
      <core-toolbar>Application</core-toolbar>
      <core-menu>
        <core-item icon="settings" label="item1"></core-item>
        <core-item icon="settings" label="item2"></core-item>
        <paper-item label="Edit Species" center horizontal layout flex>
                    <a href="/speciesEdit"></a>
                </paper-item>
      </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>
```

this jsbin demo might help you to find your problem. http://jsbin.com/xuveqi

Comment: I do see that it works in your example. I fiddled with it to to become a paper menu button. I'm simply unsure of why it won't work on my side. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

For Polymer 1.0, add `class="flex"` to each of your anchor tags. If you're using Polymer 0.5, use the `flex` attribute instead of the class.